# SQL Server 2008 R2: Querying xml nodes from a variable through a function

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two separate xml variables with identical child structure. (i.e. only the root & the first node names are different, rest structure is same.)
I want to create a function which takes the xml variable & the name of root node & returns me a table containing all the items.

These are my xml definitions(shortened for brevity)

```
declare @CartXml xml
Set @CartXml = ' <carts> 
<cart RefID="1" >

<Item SrNo="1" ProductCode="12" Qty="5">
</Item>

<Item SrNo="2" ProductCode="12" Qty="3">
</Item>
</cart>
</carts> '


declare @ProdXml xml
Set @ProdXml = ' <Products> 
<Product RefID="1" >

<Item SrNo="1" ProductCode="12" Qty="5">
</Item>

<Item SrNo="2" ProductCode="12" Qty="3">
</Item>
</Product>
</Products> '
```

I can query this via statements such as

```
 SELECT Hdr.x.value('@RefID', 'varchar(max)') CartID ,
       Det.*
 FROM   @CartXml.nodes('//carts/cart') AS Hdr(x)
 CROSS  APPLY 
          (
           SELECT 
            Det.c.value('@SrNo', 'varchar(max)') SrNo,
            Det.c.value('@ProductCode', 'varchar(max)') ProductCode,
            Det.c.value('@Qty', 'varchar(max)') Qty
            FROM   Hdr.x.nodes('Item') AS Det(c)
           ) Det
```

Replacing //carts/cart with //Products/Product & @CartXml with @ProdXml in above query will give the same output.

This query when encapsulated inside a function  does not work.

```
Create function fnTempGetprodInfoFromXml( @xml xml, @rootnode varchar(50))
returns table 
as
Return (
 SELECT Hdr.x.value('@RefID', 'varchar(max)') CartID ,
       Det.*
 FROM   @xml.nodes('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@rootnode")]') AS Hdr(x)
 CROSS  APPLY 
          (
           SELECT 
            Det.c.value('@SrNo', 'varchar(max)') SrNo,
            Det.c.value('@ProductCode', 'varchar(max)') ProductCode,
            Det.c.value('@Qty', 'varchar(max)') Qty
            FROM   Hdr.x.nodes('Item') AS Det(c)
           ) Det
)
Go


--These Dont Work
Select * from fnTempGetprodInfoFromXml(@cartxml,'carts/cart')
Select * from fnTempGetprodInfoFromXml(@ProdXml,'Products/Product')
```

I feel there is some problem in passing the node variable to the xml.nodes in the function . 
I wish I could pass '//carts/cart' instead of 'carts/cart' but the function does not compile.

This is the output required from the function.

```
CartID  SrNo ProductCode    Qty
1       1     12            5
1       2     12            3
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a parameter to the `nodes` function, it must be a string literal.

Your options are to modify your function slightly to accept the trimmed XML:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnTempGetprodInfoFromXml (@xml XML)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   SELECT  Det.c.value('@SrNo', 'varchar(max)') AS SrNo,
            Det.c.value('@ProductCode', 'varchar(max)') AS ProductCode,
            Det.c.value('@Qty', 'varchar(max)') AS Qty
    FROM    @xml.nodes('*/*/Item') AS Det(c)

);
```

Then call it slightly differently

```
DECLARE @Xml XML
SET @Xml = '<carts><cart RefID="1" ><Item SrNo="1" ProductCode="12" Qty="5">
            </Item><Item SrNo="2" ProductCode="12" Qty="3"></Item></cart></carts>';

 SELECT Hdr.x.value('@RefID', 'varchar(max)') CartID ,
        Det.*
 FROM   @Xml.nodes('//carts/cart') AS Hdr (x)
        CROSS APPLY fnTempGetprodInfoFromXml(x.query('*')) AS Det;
```

Or if you want to be more generic, then you could make your function to just return all items at the second level by using a wild card, e.g.

```
DECLARE @Xml XML
SET @Xml = '<carts><cart RefID="1" ><Item SrNo="1" ProductCode="12" Qty="5">
            </Item><Item SrNo="2" ProductCode="12" Qty="3"></Item></cart></carts>';

SELECT  Hdr.x.value('@RefID', 'varchar(max)') CartID ,
        Det.*
FROM    @xml.nodes('*/*') AS Hdr(x)
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  Det.c.value('@SrNo', 'varchar(max)') AS SrNo,
                    Det.c.value('@ProductCode', 'varchar(max)') AS ProductCode,
                    Det.c.value('@Qty', 'varchar(max)') AS Qty
            FROM    hdr.x.nodes('Item') AS Det(c)
        ) Det;
```

Beyond this you would have to use dymanic SQL, which would then mean you can't use a function.